# API for ckeditor everytime content gets loaded into it

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In **ckeditor** I want to do some operation every time new content get loaded or the existing content refreshes.

As **instanceready** and **onload** API's are getting executed only once, I am not able to do the desired operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [the `contentDom` event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom), which is fired after setting editor's data or switching editor's modes.

If you want to always do something even when only little change occurred in the content, then probably [the `change` event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) is the best option.